# GCP Cloud Scheduler ERROR with status INTERNAL for an HTTP target

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a Scheduler job that calls my function every 8 hours. The function is working without a problem and returning HTTP 200 status every time when the member is "allUsers" for the role roles/cloudfunctions.invoker. However, when I use my service account as the member via serviceAccount:${google_service_account.ServiceAccount.email}, this error appears:

```
{
   insertId: "---"
     jsonPayload: {
       status: "INTERNAL"
       @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
       targetType: "HTTP"
       jobName: "projects/projectname/locations/asia-northeast1/jobs/Function_Name"
       url: "https://asia-northeast1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/Function_Name"
}
httpRequest: {
   status: 500
}
resource: {
  type: "cloud_scheduler_job"
  labels: {
     project_id: "projectname"
     job_id: "Function_Name"
     location: "asia-northeast1"
  }
}
timestamp: "2021-05-24T08:14:39.131999796Z"
severity: "ERROR"
logName: "projects/projectname/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-05-24T08:14:39.131999796Z"
}
```

and the scheduler results to "Failed" instead of "Success.

How can I fix this error? The terraform version I'm using for Google Cloud Platform is 2.20.3. This is how the code looks like:

```golang
resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "test" {
  name             = "Function_Name_Schedule_Job"
  description      = "Triggers ${google_cloudfunctions_function.Function_Name.name} function every 8 hours."
  time_zone        = "Asia/Singapore"
  schedule         =  "59 7,15,23 * * *"
  region           = "${var.Region}"
  retry_config {
    retry_count        = 5
    max_retry_duration = "520s"
  }
  http_target  {
    uri                     = "${google_cloudfunctions_function.Function_Name.https_trigger_url}"
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = "${google_service_account.ServiceAccount.email}"
    }
  }
  depends_on = ["google_cloudfunctions_function.Function_Name"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the audience in the `oidc_token` definition. Equals to your Cloud FUnctions URL (without any additional path or argument)

```
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = "${google_service_account.ServiceAccount.email}"
      audience = "${google_cloudfunctions_function.Function_Name.https_trigger_url}"
    }
```

Comment: Hi, is "service_account_email" the one under cloud function -> details -> service account? Or my personal email I used to set up the GCP?

Comment: No, it's the cloud scheduler service account (create a new one if it doesn't exist). Not the identity of the Cloud Functions (even if technically you can use the same identity for both service, it doesn't make sense to do that)

Comment: I still got "permission denied" after adding OIDC token with cloud scheduler service account and cloud function's trigger URL.

Comment: a 403 or a 401? Are you sure that the new service account has the Cloud Functions Invoker role granted on the function (or wider on the project)?

Comment: Yes I have it set to all roles -> Cloud Invoker.  Status 403